# primeng p-treeSelect The tree remains open after selecting a child in the tree, how to shrink the tree after selecting a child

Tags: html, angular, primeng

I have a p-treeSelect, I select a child in the tree and the tree remains open and does not shrink to ancestors only, the general tree does close.
I want the tree to shrink back and then close
can you help me?

I looked for a definition on this in the primeng and did not find it

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem,
this is what I did:
I added a @viewChild variable, and then I called the hide() function in the onSelect function.
This is my code:

```js
    @ViewChild("treeselect")
    treeselect: any

    selectNode() {
      this.treeselect.hide()
    }
```

```html
    <p-treeSelect class="w-full md:w-20rem" #treeselect containerStyleClass="w-full" (onNodeSelect)="selectNode()" formControlName="treeSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedNodesArr[0]" [options]="nodes1" [metaKeySelection]="false" selectionMode="multiple" placeholder="Select Item">
    </p-treeSelect>


<p-treeSelect class="w-full md:w-20rem" #treeselect containerStyleClass="w-full" (onNodeSelect)="selectNode()" formControlName="treeSelect" [(ngModel)]="selectedNodesArr[0]" [options]="nodes1" [metaKeySelection]="false" selectionMode="multiple" placeholder="Select Item">
</p-treeSelect>
```